# Using apply to convert dates in R and handling NA dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe, apply

This seems like it should be a lot easier and I'm sure someone can help me. I'm trying to change each date to the first of its respective month from a data.frame of dates using floor_date() in the lubridate package, however some of those dates are NAs. I'd rather not substitute dummy dates for the NAs.

I've tried the below:

```
library(lubridate)
a<-c(as.Date("2011-05-04"), as.Date("2011-06-12"))
b<-c(as.Date("2012-03-01"), NA)
test <- data.frame(a,b)

apply(test, 1, function(y) sapply(y, function(x) if(!is.na(x)) floor_date(x, "month") else na.pass(x)))
apply(test, 1, function(y) ifelse(!is.na(y)), floor_date(y, "month"), na.pass(y))
```

The first call returns:

```
Error in object[[name, exact = TRUE]] : subscript out of bounds
```

The second call returns:

```
Error in update.default(x, mdays = 1, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0) : 
need an object with call component
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The big problem with all this is that `apply` is going to coerce to a matrix and all of the attributes (including what makes an R "Date" a date will be lost. You will need to use `lapply` on columns rather than working on rows.

Comment: Do you just want to convert each Date to the first of the month? If so, it makes no sense to do that by working through the rows one at a time, which is what `apply(test, 1, ....)` does. You should rather do something like `data.frame(lapply(test, ...))`. That will take each of the columns of `test` and perform the calculations on them each in turn, and then convert the resulting list of columns back into a data.frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about lubridate, but you could do this easily with the excellent date-handling facilities provided by base R.

Here's a little helper function that should perform the calculations you want without complaint:

```
firstOfMonth <- function(dates) {
    as.Date(strftime(dates, format="%Y-%m-01"))
}

firstOfMonth(a)
# [1] "2011-05-01" "2011-06-01"
firstOfMonth(b)
# [1] "2012-03-01" NA   

data.frame(lapply(test, firstOfMonth))
#            a          b
# 1 2011-05-01 2012-03-01
# 2 2011-06-01       <NA>
```

Comment: doh! I knew I was making things too complicated! Thank you so much. Also noticed lapply works better in this case than apply. Apply returns numeric vectors instead of Date class objects in this example.

Comment: Yep. It also looks like lubridate's `floor_date()` simply isn't designed to handle `NA`s, so you'll be better off just using my code or something like it. (Try `floor_date(b)` with your vector `b` to see what I mean.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried package zoo ?

```
library(zoo)
a<-c(as.Date("2011-05-04"), as.Date("2011-06-12"))
b<-c(as.Date("2012-03-01"), NA)
test <- data.frame(
        "a" = as.Date(as.yearmon(a)),
        "b" = as.Date(as.yearmon(b))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
my_floor_date <- function(x,...) {idx <- !is.na(x); x[idx] <- floor_date(x[idx], ...); x}
transform(test, a=my_floor_date(a, "month"), b=my_floor_date(b, "month"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it in a one-liner like you were trying, this would work:

```
data.frame(lapply(test,function (y) (as.Date(sapply(y,function(x) if (is.na(x)) NA else floor_date(x,'month'))))))
```

The real problem here is the `lubridate` function itself, which should allow you to pass a parameter to `update.Date` telling it to ignore NA. The `strftime` solution above is definitely the cleanest.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, the reason why your solution didn't work was because you used `apply` instead of `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

The NA bug in floor_date() is fixed in lubridate 1.1.0 which was sent to CRAN today. An NA bug in the S3 update method for dates remains (fixed in the development version). In the mean time,

```
floor_date(as.POSIXlt(test$b), unit = "month")
```

would work.